# Where does the jenkins shared library files get stored?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

The shared library files in jenkins are loaded at the beginning of the job, where does it get stored? I am trying to access the dockerfile stored in the shared library, I need the path to give in the docker build command. Is there a way I can find out the place where the shared library files are loaded in jenkins?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the shared library is loaded from SCM and your workspace path is `jenkins/workspaces/jobName`, then a copy is checked out to `jenkins/workspaces/jobName@libs` or similar (might be suffixed with a number if that path is occupied by another concurrent build).

However, [there is another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213654/how-to-invoke-bash-functions-defined-in-a-resource-file-from-a-jenkins-pipeline), if I understand you correctly you wan't to retrieve a resource in this library? In that case you should use the `libraryResource` and `writeFile` steps. Like this:

```
writeFile file:'myFile.txt', text:libraryResource("path/to/myFile.txt")
```

Comment: What is the path I should use inside libraryResource? text:libraryResource("path/to/myFile.txt") How to find the path to the file in my resource? Can you be more clear about this?

Comment: See here, https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-resources, basically, if you, in your repo, have your file in `resources/path/to/myFile.txt` then you use `libraryResource("path/to/myFile.txt")`. E.g. the files are resolved relative to the `resources/` folder.

Comment: Where will be the location of myFile.txt on the jenkins node ?

Comment: @codeGeass are you refering to {{writeFile file:'myFile.txt' ...}} then the file is written in current working directory.

Comment: Yes, in the workspace ? Could not find it, so I have written {writeFile file:"${WORKSPACE}/myFile.txt" ...}

Comment: Strange... Were you inside a dir step?

Comment: This was beacause I had stages on which I was specifying each time the agent, so Jenkins created a temporary workspace for each stage. So when I was reffering to that resource in an other stage, Jenkins could not find it because the workspace is different.

Comment: @codeGeass consider `stash`ing your files if you have multiple nodes/agents and need the files to persist from stage to stage regardless of the agent being used.

Comment: writeFile is not working for binary files in the resources.