# Where does jenkins store Global Pipeline/Shared Libraries?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Just configured a global pipeline library from `Manage Jenkins » Configure System » Global Pipeline Libraries` with implicit loading. From my job I can see the library is checked out but would like to know the exact path where the library is stored. Couldn't find the information in [this section of the documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries).

*Notes: Jenkins is installed on RHEL host and the job is running on an agent node.*

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42431969/361089

Comment: Not really. I do not see any library in workspace which probably makes sense since the library is loaded on global scope (not folder or job scope). Assuming, referenced post talks about shared library loaded from jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the location and posting in case it's helpful to anyone else.

Given, in my case the job is executing on an agent node, the library is getting copied to below location of jenkins master.

```
$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<folder>/jobs/<job_name>/builds/<build_number>/libs
```

The library is getting copied on every build.

*Note that, jobs/<folder> will come into play if the jobs are placed under a subfolder.*