# Jenkins Shared Libraries: is it possible to pass arguments to shell scripts imported as 'libraryResource'?

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following setup:

(Stripped out) Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('my-custom-library') _

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                printHello name: 'Jenkins'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my-custom-library/resources/com/org/scripts/print-hello.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello, $1"
```

my-custom-library/vars/printHello.groovy:

```
def call(Map parameters = [:]) {
    def printHelloScript = libraryResource 'com/org/scripts/print-hello.sh'
    def name = parameters.name
    //the following line gives me headaches
    sh(printHelloScript(name))
}
```

I expect `Hello, Jenkins`, but it throws the following exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String) values: [Jenkins]
>
> Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long),
>   split(java.lang.String), take(int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

So, is it possible to do something like described above, without mixing Groovy and Bash code?

Comment: Related: [How to invoke bash functions defined in a resource file from a Jenkins pipeline Groovy script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40213654/1015595)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, check out [withEnv](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables)

The example they give looks like;

```
node {
  withEnv(['MYTOOL_HOME=/usr/local/mytool']) {
    sh '$MYTOOL_HOME/bin/start'
  }
}
```

More applicable to you:

```
// resources/test.sh
echo "HI here we are - $PUPPY_DOH --"

// vars/test.groovy
def call() {
   withEnv(['PUPPY_DOH=bobby']) {
    sh(libraryResource('test.sh'))
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] libraryResource
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo HI here we are - bobby --
HI here we are - bobby --
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
```

Using that, you can pass it in using a scoped named variable, something like

```
def call(Map parameters = [:]) {
    def printHelloScript = libraryResource 'com/org/scripts/print-hello.sh'
    def name = parameters.name
    withEnv(['NAME=' + name]) { // This may not be 100% syntax here ;)
    sh(printHelloScript)
}

// print-hello.sh
echo "Hello, $name"
```

Comment: You can use `withEnv(["NAME=${name}"])` (note the double qoutes). You might also want to escape the variable contents first.